# Getting the checked value of a checkbox in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular8

Is there a way to get the checkbox's checked value in a .ts file?

Here's the html of the checkbox:

```
<label class="checkbox-container">
    <span class="remember-me-text">Billing Address same as Return Address</span>
    <input type="checkbox" id="billingCheck" name="checkbox" checked>
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Basically, I want a different the display of a div on the same component, let's say id='x', to toggle from 'none' to 'block' any time the checkbox is unchecked.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Reactive form

```
billingCheck: new FormControl(false);
ngOnInit(){
  this.billingCheck.valueChanges.subscribe(
     value=>{
        console.log('Checkbox:',value);
      })
}
```

In HTML:

```
<label class="checkbox-container">
    <span class="remember-me-text">Billing Address same as Return Address</span>
    <input type="checkbox" [formControl]="billingCheck" name="checkbox" checked>
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<pre>{{billingCheck.value | json}}</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this by:

HTML:

```
<label class="checkbox-container">
    <span class="remember-me-text">Billing Address same as Return Address</span>
    <input type="checkbox" id="billingCheck" name="checkbox" checked #myCheckBox (click)="checkboxUpdated(myCheckBox.checked)"> <--- this line
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

In TS:

```
checkboxUpdated(value: boolean) {
    console.log('value', value);
    // your logic here
}
```